# HashMap.put() is overriding existing item for different key

Tags: java, eclipse, string, hashmap

I have a HashMap which I am using to store objects of type **SplitCriteria** using a String as the key

```
Map<String, SplitCriteria> criteriaMap = new HashMap<String, SplitCriteria>();
```

A sample SplitCriteria object contains the something like the following:

```
SplitCriteria [
    id=4, 
    criteriaName="Location", 
    criteriaAbrevName="Loc", 
    fieldName="LOCATION", 
    isMandatory=false
]
```

with **id** being a long, **isMandatory** is a boolean and the rest are strings.

I am looping over previously populated Array of the same object type, total count is **7**, adding each to the HashMap using the fieldName attribute as the key:

```
for(SplitCriteria split : selectedCriteria){
    String fieldName = split.getFieldName();
    criteriaMap.put(fieldName, split);
}
```

After this loop has finished, the size of the map appears to be **7**, but looking at the table contents there are only **6** objects present.

From researching the issue, I have come to understand that if there is a clash with keys, the clashing objects are "chained" together using the `next` attribute of the entry in the Map.

From the image below, you can see this is what is happening in my scenario, but the two keys are completely different!

[image]

Also I read this in the docs for the put method

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value

and

> Returns:
>   the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.

So if the keys were clashing, I would expect the old entry to be returned, but it is not.

I have no clue how this is happening, as each key I am using is completely different to the next.

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Paddy

**EDIT:**
When I try and retrieve the object at a later stage I am getting a null reponse

```
SplitCriteria criteria = (SplitCriteria) criteriaMap.get(key);
```

Comment: I am using the fieldName attribute as the key. And as I am the one who populated the data I know none of the contents clash

Comment: One of those entries - we can't tell which - has a nonnull `next` field containing the "missing" entry.

Answer (score 5):

> but looking at the table contents there are only 6 objects present

Nope, look at `size` - it's 7. You've just got two values in the same bucket. They don't collide by exact hash value, but they *do* collide by bucket. That's fine.

You won't be able to observe that when you use the map - if you just use the public API, you'll see all 7 entries with no hint of anything untoward. This is why I would generally recommend avoiding digging into the internal details of an object using the debugger until you're really *really* sure there's a problem.

Comment: I only started digging once I was getting a null pointer on the object I was trying to retrieve

Comment: @Paddyd: Then I suggest you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem... because I don't think it's where you think it is.

Answer (score 4):

HashMap is organized into buckets.

Every bucket has a linked list with entries for that bucket.

In your case, you have sixteen buckets (the size of `table`), six of them are filled (objects in `table`), and your seven entries are in those six lists (which means that one of them has length two).

If you open those `HashMap$Entry` objects, you will find one that has a pointer to the "next" entry.

"LOCATION" and "PAY_FREQUENCY" happen to be in the same bucket.

If you continue to shove more entries into the map, it will eventually resize itself to have more buckets (to avoid running into issues with long lists).

Comment: I dont have any more entries to add. Also when i try retrieve the object using its key it returns null. Does this mean i cannot retrieve it in a conventional manner?

Comment: You should be able to retrieve both the "LOCATION" and "PAY_FREQUENCY" entries by their keys. If not, there is some problem in your code. HashMap itself is very reliable...

Answer (score 2):

Two different keys may be assigned to the same bin of the HashMap (the same array entry in Java 6 implementation). In that case they will be chained in a linked list. However, neither of these two keys overrides the other, since they are not equal to each other.

The size of your HashMap is 7, which means it contains 7 key-value pairs (even though 2 of them are stored in the same bin).

Answer (score 1):

A clash happens when two different keys produce the same hash value. This hashed value is used in the HashMap to quickly navigate to the elements. So this means, that when two keys clash, they are different but both produce the same hash value. The algorithm that is used to calculate the hash value is internal to the HashMap.
Take a look at this blog post: http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/08/hashing-how-hash-map-works-in-java-or.html

Comment: "The algorithm that is used to calculate the hash value is internal to the HashMap." Actually, HashMap uses `Object#hashCode`.

Comment: That might be true, but it is not in the contract of HashMap, so Oracle might decide to use a different algorithm from one day to the other.

Comment: @hotzst Your answer is correct. entries are put into buckets based on the values of `h ^ (h >>> 16)` where `h` is `Object#hashCode`. This additional hash **is** internal to `HashMap`, and it is subject to change . It *has* changed. It used to be different.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: What happens to that value afterwards (to map it onto buckets) is of course implementation-dependent and subject to change.  But I just checked, and the Javadoc for HashMap does not even say that `hashCode` is used at all in the calculation. Which seems weird.

Comment: @Thilo It mentions in passing that: `Note that using many keys with the same hashCode() is a sure way to slow down performance of any hash table`.

Answer (score 0):

The table only has `16` entries. This means that keys are assigned to buckets only based on `4` bits, so two entries in the same bucket isn't that unlikely at all. The table will grow as you add more entries.

You don't need to care about these details. All you should care about is that the map has `7` entries.

Answer (score 0):

Since hashcode is same for both the keys, bucket location would be same and collision will occur in HashMap, Since HashMap use LinkedList to store object, this entry (object of Map.Entry comprise key and value )  will be stored in LinkedList.

HashMap uses Key Object's hashcode to find out bucket location and retrieves Value object ,then there are two Value objects are stored in same bucket . HashMap  stores both Key and Value in LinkedList node .
After finding bucket location , we will call keys.equals() method to identify correct node in LinkedList and return associated value object for that key in Java HashMap